# Unable to locate package libc-dev-i386

Tags: ubuntu

I'm getting this error when trying to install this package on Ubuntu 12 64bit. I have already done a sudo apt-get update but still does not find it. Any way to fix this issue (libc6-i386 is already installed)?

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/246241/ubuntu-12-10-package-libc6-dev-i386-is-not-available

Comment: I tried to do what they say, but it didnt work